# TransactionScope, where is begin transaction on sql profiler?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, transactionscope

i need to do something like this on a transaction context

```
using(var context = new Ctx())
{

using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    decimal debit = 10M;
    int id = 1;

    var data = context.Cashier
        .Where(w => w.ID == id)
        .Select(s => new{ s.Money })
        .Single();


    Cashier cashier = new Cashier(){ ID = id };
    context.Cashier.Attach(cashier);

    cashier.Money = data.Money - debit;
    context.Entry(cashier).Property(p => p.Money ).IsModified = true;

    context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None);
    tran.Complete();
}
}
```

I'm running sql profiler but can't see begin tran, is that block of code correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly you have then filtered out? You might also try having the ctx creation inside the transaction, just to see I that changes anything.

Comment: Why are you using transaction scope for this block of code? `SaveChanges` uses transaction internally if you do not define it so unless you are using multiple transactional resources or calling `SaveChanges` multiple times you do not need it.

Comment: Ladislav, it's to prevent wrong data, someone else can modify the cashier money on another methods, if it's not on transaction, this info will be wrong

Comment: @Alexandre: @Ladislav is correct; the `SaveChanges` function always uses a transaction when saving. Unless you are calling `SaveChanges` multiple times (or doing other database manipulation within this block of code), there's no need for another transaction.

Comment: I understand that Adam, but the begin tran of entity framework occures only when calls SaveChanges, I need the transaction before this, more specifically on: context.Cashier
        .Where(w => w.ID == id)
        .Select(s => new{ s.Money })
        .Single();

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like @Marc said in his comment, the messages are probably being filtered out. You would only be picking up T-SQL transaction messages in the default profile, not transaction messages that are sent using the API directly (as `TransactionScope` does).

In SQL Server Profiler, go to the trace event selection and check the "Show All Events" checkbox. Down at the bottom is a "Transactions" category, and it should give you what you need. Specifically, the events starting with `TM:`.